# AppleScript create URL & anchor text, pass to clipboard as URL type data

Tags: url, applescript, clipboard

Is there a way to take a text label and an URL and use Applescript add them to the Mac clipboard such that rich-text apps see the data as a URL and make linked anchor text when pasting in the data.

I have untitled reference URLs (generated via code) that need to have a 'screen' title (anchor text). I can create the URL and anchor text. But, how do I combine them so that the Mac clipboard treats the data as a URL? I tried:

```
set the clipboard to "<a href=\"" & theURI & "\" target=\"_blank\">" & theAnchor & "</a>"
```

..but when using this data from other apps I get the HTML string and not a link with the anchor text as the visible screen text.

StandardAdditions has 'URL' and 'web page' classes but I can't see how to apply them. This compiles but fails when run:

```
set myURL to theURI as URL
set myLinkAnchor to theAnchor as text
set linkURL to {URL: myURL, name: myLinkAnchor} as web page
```

Comment: If you use the `handle CGI request` command, you get a `web page`.
From the `web page`, you can change these properties or get a `Internet address`.
From the `Internet address`, you can change these properties or get a `URL`.
From the URL, you can change these properties.
But you can not create them.

Comment: Thanks. As the scenario requires the URL are created via the script this shuts that avenue.  The AS documentation, and the books I have, don't really cover this. I guess the original AS assumption was that you'd never want a URL *except* as part of the `handle CGI request`. Still, it would help if the docs made it clear the `web page` class could not be used in other contexts, e.g. in scenarios like this!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't assume that all applications accept HTMLand convert it automatically into a clickable string. Your ability to do this depends on how the target application handles rich text. Some may use Cocoa's built-in rich text area classes while others may have their own completely custom text areas, each handling URLs their own way. You can look in the target application's Dictionary to see if it allows you to create URLs in an identifiable way.

Comment: The target app isn't AppleScript-able** but if a URL is dragged from a browser

Comment: I'm not worried about *all* applications. I just want to create the same info on the clipboard as would be made by copying a URL in a web browser location bar. The target apps I have in mind cope find with such data. The target app isn't AppleScript-able, thus the desire to use the clipboard. If the source app (Yojimbo) allowed you to drag a Yojimbo in-link I'd be fine. But sadly it passes a link to the Yojimbo item's reference asset and not the item itself - and I need the latter.

Comment: It always goes back to the applications as they will treat what appears to the same data differently. The ability to parse what is in the clipboard is up to the applications themselves. If I drag a link from Safari to the Desktop, it creates a text clipping, not a URL. The object you are dragging in Yojimbo is not a URL, it is a Yojimbo object holding a URL. The same goes with the URL itself. If I copy a URL from Safari, then it will give a different value than if I copy the URL from Word, despite the fact that they appear as a string of text.

Comment: I see now - thanks for the nudge! Indeed, the code suggested here: http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=152816#p152816 works in TextEdit not not my intended target app. Looks like I need to take another approach or try to mimic the data in a Safari URL drag, whatever that is. I'll mark your reply as the answer as if there is a solution to the above problem, it isn't via the route I imagined!

Comment: "if there is a solution to the above problem, it isn't via the route I imagined!" --- With Applescript, it rarely is these days.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript does support putting hex encoded HTML into the clipboard:

```
set the clipboard to «data HTML3c6120687265663d22687474703a2f2f7777772e69727261646961746564736f6674776172652e636f6d22207461726765743d225f626c616e6b223e4972726164696174656420536f6674776172653c2f613e»
```

It's pretty round-about, but here's how to do what you want:

```
set theURI to "http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com"
set theAnchor to "Irradiated Software"
set the clipboard to "<a href=\"" & theURI & "\" target=\"_blank\">" & theAnchor & "</a>"
set theHEX to do shell script "pbpaste | hexdump -ve '1/1 \"%.2x\"'"
if theHEX is "" then
    beep
else
    run script "set the clipboard to «data HTML" & theHEX & "»"
end if
```

YMMV.  I tried pasting this into Word 2011 and it worked fine.  I couldn't get Pages to take take the paste.  Also, I tried pasting into a new email message (Mail.app), and the link is fine, but you can't click on it.  However, the recipient can click on the link.